# Abstract class does not implement interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have an interface so class writers are forced to implement certain methods. I also want to allow some default implemented methods, so I create a abstract class. The problem is that all classes inherit from the base class so I have some helper functions in there.

I tried to write `: IClass` in with the abstract base, but I got an error that the base didn't implement the interface. Well of course because I want this abstract and to have the users implement those methods. As a return object if I use base I can't call the interface class methods. If I use the interface I can't access base methods.

How do I make it so I can have these helper classes and force users to implement certain methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the interface methods into the abstract class and declare them abstract as well. By this, deriving classes are forced to implement them. If you want default behaviour, use abstract classes, if you want to only have the signature fixed, use an interface. Both concepts don't mix.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure methods in the base class have the same name as the interface, and they are public. Also, make them virtual so that subclasses can override them without hiding them.

```
interface IInterface {
   void Do();
   void Go();
}

abstract class ClassBase : IInterface {

    public virtual void Do() {
         // Default behaviour
    }

    public abstract void Go();  // No default behaviour

}

class ConcreteClass : ClassBase {

    public override void Do() {
         // Specialised behaviour
    }

    public override void Go() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having faced with the same problem recently, I've came up with a somewhat more elegant (to my mind) solution. It looks like:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    void CommonMethod();
    void SpecificMethod();
}

public abstract class CommonImpl
{
    public void CommonMethod() // note: it isn't even virtual here!
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonImpl.CommonMethod()");
    }
}

public class Concrete : CommonImpl, IInterface
{
    void SpecificMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Concrete.SpecificMethod()");
    }
}
```

Now, according to C# spec (13.4.4. Interface mapping), in the process of mapping `IInterface` on `Concrete` class, compiler will look up for `CommonMethod` in `CommonImpl` too, and it doesn't even have to be virtual in the base class!

The other significant advantage, compared to Mau's solution, is that you don't have to list every interface member in the abstract base class.

Comment: I prefer Mau's solution. It's explicit and make the compiler do the conformance work for you. In this solution, you could forget to add the IInterface to the derived class.

Comment: @PlayTank: ...and then eventually it's going to fail on some implicit conversion, also at compile time. Though I agree the solution lacks some articulate strictness.